# Video driver + resolution fix on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, video, resolution, intel-graphics, edid

I have an engineering laptop (quad core IB, intel HD4000 graphics, VGA output). Intel don't do a specific "Intel HD 4000" driver for Windows 8.1 x64, they let Microsoft produce a driver instead.  I don't know if the Microsoft driver is rebadged Intel, or whether hacks exist to force other versions of Intel drivers to install. VGA 1920x1200 works fine with the same cable+monitor and my desktop.

The monitor is a Dell and I have its driver, which I've installed. It runs 1920x1200 native, and I can see using MonInfo that Windows is getting the EDID info correctly and this is recognised as its capability in MonInfo. But I cannot persuade Windows do offer an option of a 1920x1200 mode. I can't change the mode to "list all modes" in a way that lists 1920x1200, Phoenix doesn't find a valid EDID in the registry (and wouldn't really know how to fix it except following some recipe online).

Solutions online seem to be based on "list all modes" (doesn't work), modding the cable to kill EDID (drastic!), or using Intel's control panel (doesn't offer custom modes), or editing EDID.

I don't know a thing about VGA timings. What can I do to get the 1920x1200 working?

Comment: this is the latest driver fro the HD4000 I can find: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25977/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-10-and-Windows-7-8-1-15-33- Try this one

Comment: have you tried this driver?